# Making Bootstrap column padding different for different screen sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to make bootstrap column padding or margins different for columns depending on which screen size?

I have columns like this

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">...</div>
<div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">...</div>
```

I want to have different padding at each screen size especially at the smallest screen size. Is this possible?

Can someone give an example?

Comment: You can customize your css (padding)

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#components

Comment: You can use `media-query` for that

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap uses the following variables to define padding:

- padding-base-vertical
- padding-base-horizontal
- padding-large-vertical:
- padding-large-horizontal
- padding-small-vertical
- padding-small-horizontal
- padding-xs-vertical
- padding-xs-horizontal

Let's use padding-base-vertical as an example. If you are using Less, then do something like this in your main stylesheet:

```
// import bootstrap.less into your stylesheet
@import vendor/bootstrap.less
// set padding and other styles
body {
  color: #444;
  @padding-base-vertical: 10px;
  @media all and (min-width: 768px) {
    @padding-base-vertical: 15px;
  }
}
```

If you are using Sass, the approach is a little different, and easier. Look for the [_variables.scss file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss) and find $padding-base-vertical etc. Edit as desired.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.test-div{ padding:20px}
@media (max-width:767px){
  .test-div{ padding:30px}
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 test-div">...</div>
<div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">...</div>
```

such as,you can write your own code

Answer (score 0):

you may use `@media(){}` that you may used to make paddings and columns depending on the size of the screen and you might want to use also `!important` to override the default col-sm/xs margin and padding.